# Upper Case Table Names Hibernate Version 5

Tags: hibernate, mariadb, hibernate-mapping

Is there any property in `hibernate.cfg.xml` to create tables through Hibernate in Upper Case.

I'm using Hibernate version 5 with MariaDB Version 10

Comment: `@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")` try this once

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has different naming strategies : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/naming.html

The PhysicalNamingStrategy seems to be what you need.

Comment: i did implement this but no result

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate is based on JPA, so on your entities you can put the @Table annotation to set the name of the Table inside you Database.

Just put the name in Uppercase.

Comment: I did put my entity names in upper case but they are still being generated in lower case